# What is the probability of rolling a 7, given the first die was odd?

Tags: probability

I think the answer is 1/2. Given the first die was odd, you rolled either a 1,3, or 5. Now on the second roll only a 6,4, or a 2 will give you a sum of 7. Given that is half of the sample space of the second die, it is 1/2?

Comment: 1,3,5 each have exactly one number which add to 7: 6,4 and 2 respectively. So the answer is 1/6.

Comment: I see what you are saying. There is only one number that can combine with the odd to give it a sum of 7. 1 out of 6 #'s. Thank you @mathreadler

Answer (score 2):

I will try and expand a bit with a table. Since we got the one to one relationship I described in the comment above, we can see that 7 occurs exactly once for each column. So instead of having to sum up 3/18 we can count one of the columns and get 1/6. Only a save of a factor of 3 for this example, but it would be an important save if they were 10 or 100 sided dice! :)

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline + & 1 & 3 & 5\\\hline 1 &2&4&6\\\hline 2& 3& 5& \bf 7 \\ \hline 3 & 4&6&8 \\\hline 4& 5&\bf 7&9 \\ \hline 5 & 6 & 8  & 10 \\ \hline 6&\bf 7&9&11 \\\hline\end{array}$$

If you study more advanced probability and engineering you will learn about moment and probability generating functions. Sums of random variables have probability density functions (pdf) which are convolutions of the individual pdf:s. Then one can use properties of the fourier transform to explain all of this in a more elegant fashion.